Inner tube valve leaks at high pressure
I installed a new 27 x 1 1/4 inner tube recently that did not leak when inflated to low pressure (ballooning to about 3cm diameter) on the bench but leaks through the valve when inflated to riding pressure on the wheel. Do I need to replace the Schrader valve?

Removing the Schrader valve (using an improvised valve removal tool made by clamping 2 panel pins separated by about 3mm in vice grip tool) and reinserting it seems to have fixed the problem - air is no longer leaking through the valve at high pressure.

Very clever fix! I’m happy it worked.

Nice work - sorry I missed this question originally.  Another option is to add some light threadlocker or superglue or even grease on the thread when assembling the valve core into the stem, which reduces the chance of leaks or it rattling loose over time.

Just removing the valve core?
